# WCF Service for two type of clients, only one with callback

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding, wcf-callbacks

I want to create a WCF service for two types of clients

1- for windows phone 7

2- for windows (wpf)

and I want to support callback for (wpf client) only, since i dont' need it for windows phone 7 (and I think it doesnt support it)

I have no problem for creating two endpoints (wsDualHttp for WPF client and basic for WP7) but when I add callback feature WP7 does not understand the whole service.